# Find function in R

Tags: r, function, find

I have the cumulative sum of days per month as:

```
N_days_months = c(31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31)

N_days_months_cum <- cumsum(N_days_months)
```

and a variable equal to:

```
DOY_first = 239
```

when I apply the `find` function:

```
IND_DUM <- find(DOY_first < N_days_months_cum)
```

I get the following error: `**Error: is.character(what) is not TRUE**`

- How can I solve this issue?
- Could someone explain what the `find` function is doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find()` function takes character strings and looks for objects in memory. You are trying to find the first position in a numeric vector where some condition is true. Try this.

Doing the comparison returns a logical vector. The last five entries in `N_days_months_cum` are greater than 239.

```
DOY_first < N_days_months_cum
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

We can use `which()` to return the indices of a logical vector where the value is `TRUE`.

```
which(DOY_first < N_days_months_cum)
[1]  8  9 10 11 12
```

To get the first value, subset the outcome of which.

```
which(DOY_first < N_days_months_cum)[1]
[1] 8
```

If you want the first value in `N_days_months_cum` that matches this index, subset that vector with the above.

```
N_days_months_cum[which(DOY_first < N_days_months_cum)[1]]
[1] 244
```